# How to derive new column and value from a column in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to extract key and value from a column which is denoted with '=' and need to create a column respectively for each key

Below column 'PATH' have pair of key value

```
-----------------------------------------
PATH
-----------------------------------------
country=AE;subject=NGDP_RPCH;Frequency=A
country=UK;subject=NGF_RPCH;Frequency=B
country=QE;subject=GGDP_RPCH;Frequency=B
```

#Expected:

i want to extract each pair to create new column and value

Eg

```
country  |  subject|  Frequecny
---------|---------|-----------
AE       |NGDP_RPCH| A
```

i see many example for extracting json data type, but not for this
Any solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use split and regexp_replace:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, regexp_replace

df =  df.withColumn("country", regexp_replace(split(df['PATH'], ';').getItem(0), "country=", "")) \
        .withColumn("subject", regexp_replace(split(df['PATH'], ';').getItem(1), "subject=", "")) \
        .withColumn("frequency", regexp_replace(split(df['PATH'], ';').getItem(2),"Frequency=", ""))
```